# Rescheduling the task when celery worker node crashes

Tags: python, celery

In celery the worker node which is executing the task crashes in a mid-way through the task. Does the celerey reschedules the task excution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by default, however, you can set the `acks_late` option on the task, or the `task_acks_late` option globally, to get that behavior. See:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#should-i-use-retry-or-acks-late

> The acks_late setting would be used when you need the task to be
>   executed again if the worker (for some reason) crashes mid-execution.

Comment: If the task is not idempotent and the worker crashes in mid-execution of this task, acks_late will be not be useful, actually nothing can be done.